# Using class options in LyX

Tags: lyx, texlive, document-classes, lyx-layouts, documentclass

I've recently installed TeXlive and LyX. Now I'm trying to write a document using the tufte-book class. But I can't find any way to make the text column justified or make section, chapter numbers visible. I googled to find that they can be set as document class options. How to implement these in lyx?

Comment: See menu `Document` → `Settings`. At tab `Document Class` you can not only select the class, but also set class options. See also section "3.1.2 Document Classes" in the build in LyX User's Guide in the Help menu.

Comment: That helped! Thank you so much!